# WordPress permalink removing search results &swpmtx= after url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Our search plugins needs to add ?swpmtx=[random string] at the end of the url in order to enable the click tracking, but somehow our WordPress server automatically remove this when you click on the search results. Is there a RewriteRule I need to add on htaccess in order to let the tracking url work as intended?

We have YoastSEO installed but I'm not sure if this plugin would cause it too?